# FBSDKLoginManager error code 308 and singleton does not resolve it

Tags: objective-c, swift, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using Facebook iOS SDK 4.5.1 . Didn't want to use 4.6 as it force login flow to SafariVirwcontrollee only.

I always get error 308 when trying to login if FBSDKLoginManager was called before. Creating singleton as other threads suggested does not work

To summarize error 308 occured in two cases
1. Call login twice.
2. Logout and then login again.

Here is the code for singleton

```
static FBSDKLoginManager *sharedLoginManager = nil;

+(FBSDKLoginManager*)sharedLoginManager;
{
 static dispatch_once_t  oncePredecate;
dispatch_once(&oncePredecate,^{
    sharedLoginManager=[[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];



});

return sharedLoginManager;
}

- (id)init {
if (self = [super init]) {

}
return self;
```

}

Code to login

```
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
{
    [self processLoginInfo];
} else
{


    [FBSDKSettings enableLoggingBehavior:FBSDKLoggingBehaviorNetworkRequests];

    [[FacebookLoginSingleton sharedLoginManager] logOut];
    [[FacebookLoginSingleton sharedLoginManager]
     logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile",@"email",@"user_friends"]
     handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
         if (error) {//}
}];
```

Code to logout

```
    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
     {

         [[FacebookLoginSingleton sharedLoginManager] logOut];


         [FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil];
     }
```

Comment: Unclear. Show some code.

Comment: did you find out any solution to this?

Comment: Yes, it is the behaviour that happening when we run the app with Xcode. Look at the answer below

Answer (score 1):

I'm still dealing with this same error, and (assuming your info.plist, AppDelegate, and Facebook app are set up correctly), **the issue completely goes away when not running the app with Xcode**.

Yeah, it appears to be a bug where the only solution is to not use the debugging tools.

If you need to debug the login flow, there are probably a dozen different ways to do it outside if Xcode, but I had crashlytics installed and just let it log the crash enough times until I got out all the other kinks in my login code.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10588166)

Comment: The answer is that it's a bug with the SDK and to resolve it until it's fixed, don't run it in the debugger. Maybe I wasn't clear about that?